# How to merge two columns in pandas with length different

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 df

- In first df there are 3 columns, 10 rows, 3rd column is output column
- In second Df there are 3 columns 1000 rows
- If my first df 2 column matches with 2 columns of second df then 3rd column from first df has to append second df.

both df is below

df1

```
,A,B,output
1,abc,CCE,out1
2,def,CCE,out2
3,ghi,CCE,out3
4,hij,CCE,out4
5,klm,,out5
```

df2

```
,A,B
1,abc,CCE
2,def,CCE
3,lmn,CCE
4,opq,CCE
5,abc,CCE
6,klm,,
```

df2_expected

```
1,abc,CCE,out1
2,def,CCE,out2
3,lmn,CCE,
4,opq,CCE,
5,abc,CCE,out1
6,klm,,out5
```

As example i am giving 3 column actually in first df its n column and df2 its n-1 column means output column wont present in df2

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny first one serial number

Comment: Isn't this basic `merge`?

Comment: My thoughts exactly, or I don't undertand this part (_if my first df 2 column matches with 2 columns of second df_) correctly

Comment: pd.merge(df1, df2,  how='right', left_on=df1.columns.tolist(), right_on = df12.columns.tolist())

Comment: @Mayeulsgc i tried with above code, got error  ValueError: len(right_on) must equal len(left_on)

Comment: @Mayeulsgc i dont have output column in the df2, it will come from df1

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny my column names wont ['A','B']. it will change everytime

Comment: suggest closing this -- read pandas documentation on merge, concatenate and append

Comment: If your actual question is how to find common columns between two dfs so you can merge, use `df1.columns&df2.columns`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this

```
import pandas as pd
data1={'nu':[1,2,3,4,5], 'A':['abc','def','ghi','hij','klm'], 'B':['CCE','CCE','CCE','CCE','CCE'], 'output':['out1','out2','out3','out4','out5',]}
data2={'nu':[1,2,3,4,5], 'A':['abc','def','lmn','opq','abc'], 'B':['CCE','CCE','CCE','CCE','CCE'], 'output':[]}
df1=pd.DataFrame(data1,columns=['A','B','output'], index=data1['nu'])
df2=pd.DataFrame(data2,columns=['A','B'], index=data2['nu'])
df2.merge(df1, on=['A','B'],how='left').fillna('')


   A    B   output
0   abc CCE out1
1   def CCE out2
2   lmn CCE 
3   opq CCE 
4   abc CCE out1
```

Comment: my column names wont ['A','B']. it will change everytime , can you put df1.columns.tolist()

Comment: you are saying that your column names of df2 shouldn't be affected ryt?